# passing objects between 2 applications in separate JVMs

Tags: session, jvm, websphere-portal

I have a portlet application running on a portal server and an webapp running on application server. I want to make a call from the portlet application jsp to app application. I can make the call; no issues.. I can pass values in the request parameter; no issues.. I want to pass an object to the appserver application as well and I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Java RMI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/). After implementing couple of interfaces you can pass objects between JVM's quite easily. As Laird mentioned, that requires serialization, but it is often done implicitly by Java, so there's a good chance you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your two applications are running on two separate application servers, and hence on two different Java Virtual Machines, the only way to pass an object from one to the other is by serializing the object in some fashion.

You may opt to use Java serialization, or you may choose to represent your object in terms of its state and then have a class--deployed separately to each application server somewhere--that knows how to build a new instance of your object out of that state.

Answer (score 0):

Is your appserver a Websphere Application Server? Maybe [Dynacache](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/liaag/cache/pubwasdynacachoverview.htm) could be what you are looking for. A college told me a story from his current project, they need to access data from a Java EE app running on Websphere 7, Portal environment is 6.1.